# Use ViewModel for select in one div in another div

Tags: knockout.js

Can you create a view model from two different `div` elements??

I have one drop down in a `div` tag and I'm binding some country values by using an AJAX method.

Later I have called ko.applyBindings on it with its div name (let it be "divCountry").

Now in the second div I had put 2 text boxes. I want to save the text box values as well as the selected item from drop down in first div. But every time I try thyis I am not getting the correct selected value.

If I put a dummy label in the "divCountry" databound with drop down value, it is showing me correct value of selected item.

Comment: Please include code in your question demonstrating the issue, and be specific about your problem.

Comment: Why Downvotes!!? For not posting code???  Here we go  http://jsfiddle.net/dqUAz/338/

Comment: Whenever i click Add Button it should alert(args)..where args:{"argBO":{"availableCountries":[],"StateName":"rfdgsf","ShortName":"df","id":2}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined your `stateViewModel` as a function, not as an object. Knockoutjs doesn't know what to do with that when you try to bind that. Therefor, `$parent` is undefined. As indicated by the error message in the console, which you should have seen as well:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "with: function (){return StateModel }"
Message: Unable to process binding "click: function (){return $parent.Submit }"
Message: Cannot read property 'Submit' of undefined
```

Comment: Yea your right!! Actually this fiddle is just for an understanding of what is my requirement, But here the main requirement is i want to get the selected item's 'id' in the args...jsfiddle.net/dqUAz/341 , can i get it? –

Comment: @Aj_sari, why do you keep using 2 separate viewmodels? Not that it is wrong in any way, but you seem to complicate things for yourself. If you'd just move `availableCountries` from `viewModel` to `StateModel` an change you bindings accordingly. If that's not a possibility, then how would you access from an object a property located in another object?

Comment: @Aj_sari, just a jsfiddle? What do you want to say with that? Why don't you answer or try to answer my previous questions?

Comment: I have binded only one time by following what u said, by creating only one viewmodel.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51816/discussion-between-aj-sari-and-major-byte)

Comment: is there any way to hide countrylist in observable in stateModel,,,because of this I am getting error in firebug:" Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" I am posting the args value in ajax, a huge list of countrieslist is also being posted, due to this i am getting the error!!